# I have a string, in that how to find a image string and replace with another?

Tags: php

I have a string, how to find image path and replace with full URL using PHP.

```
"testing testing test.png testing",
```

in that string, how to find `test.png` and replace with:

```
<img src='/uploads/test.png'>
```

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: Man I have to learn regex. So do you

Comment: Employ child slave labour to go through and manually make the changes?

Comment: @CD001 That actually is what some huge software companies do in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small example to demonstrate how to use "regular expressions" for such task:

```
<?php
$input = "testing testing test.png testing";
$output = preg_replace('/\s(test\.png)\s/', "<img src='uploads/\\1'>", $input);
var_dump($output);
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
string(53) "testing testing <img src='/uploads/test.png'> testing"
```

---

In your comment below you *probably* ask how to keep this flexible and accept *any* file name, as long as it has a `.png` "file name extension". Do I get that right?

If so, then take a look at this generalized modification:

```
<?php
$input = "testing testing test.png testing";
$output = preg_replace('/\s(\w+\.png)\s/', "<img src='uploads/\\1'>", $input);
var_dump($output);
```

---

A variant accepting different specific "file name extensions":

```
<?php
$input = "testing testing test.png testing";
$output = preg_replace('/\s(\w+\.(png|jpg|gif))\s/', "<img src='uploads/\\1'>", $input);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: in a string "?.png" , how to take whole file name using with .png extenstion?

Comment: @user7290594 I extended the given answer.

Comment: for suppose 2 or 3 extensions is there, how to change expression , i mean .jpg, .png like that. @arkascha

Comment: @user7290594 Extended the answer by another variant. However... don't you think it would be time for you to take the head start you got here and start learning about regular expressions yourself? Possibly experimenting a little with one of the online tools that allow to play around with expressions?